# Error de Casteo de una Query en Spring

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate

**PROBLEMA AL HACER EL CASTEO DE UNA QUERY DE SQL A UNA TABLA MAPEADA, PARA PODER MOSTRAR EL RESULTADO DE MI CONSULTA EN UNA TABLA EN FRONT END.**

```
    @Transactional("txsManagerSHOP")
    @RequestMapping(value = "getShopTable", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody ModelAndView getShopTable(ModelMap model,@RequestParam String shopO) {
        try {
            String UrlPart = "http://gdl1amwebw03:8080/WebServiceCirrus/Part/PartNumber/FindPartNumberByShopOrder/"
                    + shopO;
            String partNumber = StringView(UrlPart);
            TableShopOrder partN =  (TableShopOrder) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createNativeQuery("SELECT top 1 [serial_qty] FROM [dba_Shop_Order].[dbo].[shop_order] where [shop_order]="+ "'" + partNumber + "'").uniqueResult();
            model.addAttribute("model", partN);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return new ModelAndView("ShopOrder", model) ;
    }
```

**Error**

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to com.Sanmina.ChangePartNumber.model.TableShopOrder
at com.Sanmina.ChangePartNumber.controller.Controller.getShopTable(Controller.java:235)
at com.Sanmina.ChangePartNumber.controller.Controller$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$3e7c2cb8.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:721)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:656)
at com.Sanmina.ChangePartNumber.controller.Controller$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$af693056.getShopTable(<generated>)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:94)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:509)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1104)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1524)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1480)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Hola @Melissa y bienvenida a StackOverflow en español. Si tienes un rato te agradeceríamos que echaras un vsitazo al [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y te pasaras por el [centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help) para entender mejor como funciona este sitio. Comentar además que simplemente código, mensaje de error y un título no suele ser suficiente para que te podamos ayudar con el problema. Por favor, edite la pregunta ampliando información sobre su problema.

Comment: Necesitamos el código relevante donde sale la excepción. El código que provees carece de la información necesaria para el análisis. Puesto que usas hibernate, conviene que proveas: 1) la entidad mapeada, 2) el query (hql, criteria o lo que estés usando), 3) el código que muestra la ejecución del query.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que te dice la excepción es que estás tratando de hacer un cast de un elemento del tipo `BigDecimal` a un objeto del tipo `TableShopOrder`. Esto quiere decir que la query que estás lanzando no devuelve el objeto `TableShopOrder` que tú esperas, si no un `BigDecimal`. Asegúrate que la query está bien formada.